# Which is the best way to clean the contact points on the RAM?

Tags: memory

Whenever I face a RAM issue in PC's or I want to clean the contact points on the RAM, I used to remove the RAM from its socket and rub its "copper contacts" with a eraser.
Is it good to clean the RAM's "contacting leads" with an eraser?

Should I use any alternative method?

Comment: It is better to use water or alcohol with cotton buds so that the dust would be stick to it and this helps to prevent moving dust to another part.Dont use vacuum cleaner which has more force and would damage the circuit

Comment: tbh, simple pushing & pulling the RAM in & out of its slot will clean up the contacts. They're designed that way.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to clean RAM is using **a piece of cotton smeary to alcohol** or **'Computer Cleaning Kits'** (specially inner-case) gently touching RAM's base.

and to clean it's slot you can also use a **used brush with alcohol** Or a can of compressed air (designed to clean hardware slots or inner-buttons)

and your second question about using eraser: actually that's a way too but i don't recommend it, cause it can damage your RAM, rust contacting leads totally Or make it thin and cut the contact to slot off.

hope it helps!

Comment: Note:  Among other edits I changed the words "some kind of sprays" to "compressed air" as I assume that what the OP meant.  Hope I did not change the intention of the answer.

Comment: yes @davidgo! tnx for your note!

Comment: ok. and what happens when I use an eraser

Comment: @Anbu Sorry! Answer updated.

Comment: yes it is no longer a good idea to apply the eraser method anymore, the gold platings to reduce oxidations are way thinner than long ago when eraser methods would work without stripping it completely. a good microfiber rag should clean enough if needed, without leaving any lint.

Comment: if the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accept to help others.